# CSS: center <li> items in the page and next to eachother?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to center `<li>` items in the page and next to each other without any luck!

I have tried all sorts of ways from `display:table;` to `magin:0 auto;` and `display:block;` and `display:inline-block;` etc etc... and unfortunately nothing seems to work.

To explain this I've created this [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/h1m9aog6/)

Please expand the HTML section of that fiddle to see the menu items in the normal mode (green bar).

the CSS Code that I have been messing around with is this part:

```
nav {
    /*position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 5px;*/

}
nav li {
    float: left;

    display: inline-block;
}
nav li a {
    font-size: 11px;
    color: #9aa6af;
    padding: 24px 15px;

    display: block;
}
nav li a:hover {color: #000;}
```

could someone please advise on this issue?

any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't use floats and you'll never have problems :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to manipulate the `<ul>` parent, for example in your jsfiddle setting `display: table; margin: 0 auto;` to the `nav` will center the nav menu

Comment: nice one dude. that did it nicely.

Answer (score 4):

[basicly you can do](https://jsfiddle.net/h1m9aog6/1/) :

```
nav {
    /*position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 5px;*/
  text-align:center

}
nav li {    
    display: inline-block;
}
```

`Float` kills `display` and cannot be centered

Comment: No, i can't. because it will ruin the responsiveness of the menu. reduce the size of the HTML section in that fiddle again to see the responsive menu and see what happened to it with your example!

Comment: @rooz the probleme you show comes from your nav set at 93% (in mediaqueries) width , put it at 240px (balck portion shown) and it is working fine https://jsfiddle.net/h1m9aog6/5/

Comment: @rooz you should fix this, else you'll  find out once you have a text link too long to fit in it :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this technique:

```
/* center nav */
nav > ul { /* center ul */
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    left: 50%;
}

nav > ul > li { /* compensate ul position */
    float: left;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    right: 50%;
}

nav > ul > li > a {
    display: block;
}
```

I've updated your fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/tianes/h1m9aog6/4/

Answer (score 1):

on `ul` apply this

```
ul
 {
  display: table; 
  margin: 0 auto
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
nav {
    /*position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 5px;*/
    text-align:center
 }
 nav li {    
    display: inline-block;
 }
```